# Japanese IME on Windows: switch back to romaji input method

Tags: windows, ime, japanese

There are apparently two ways to work a Japanese keyboard:

1. type alphabetic characters (romaji) and translate them. ( t+a = ta, t+e = te, and so on)
2. every key is assigned a single kana (q = ta, w = te and so on).

No one I know uses the second method.

Somehow the IME (on Windows XP) got switched into the second method.

How can I switch it back?

**Update:** I have restarted the computer in the mean-time, and that put it back to normal.

Comment: what does your language bar show?

Comment: [JA] [red icon:IME Japanese standard] [あ] [般]

Comment: it should be a blue icon.

Comment: did you press double-shift or any of the weird, annoying keyboard change locks?

Comment: @scoopdreams: with a toddler in the house, this is totally possible.

Comment: @Thilo san, you have installed a US Keyboard, and after that connect a Japanese Keyboard, for this you need to configure Windows to recognize the new keyboard, see "Caliban" answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to toggle direct kana input.

On a Japanese keyboard, try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + the <kbd>カタカナ|ひらがな|ローマ字</kbd> key (to the right of the space key).
With Windows 7 you get a confirmation dialog in case you accidentally hit this key combination.

Comment: That does not seem to do anything. Maybe I am doing it wrong. I have a Japanese keyboard. Does Alt+' mean (Alt-Shift-7) or (Alt-Shift-@)?

Comment: The ` Key on an US Keyboard is the Top-Leftmost key (Just under the Esc Key). Try pressing that. Otherwise (Alt-Shift-@) looks correct

Comment: Alt+` toggles between alphabetic and hiragana input mode, not between direct-kana. There is a little button on the language bar reading [kana] which is only visible in the 'restored' state (not in the start bar) which you should depress to get rid of it. I'm still looking for the key combination for this button as it often turns on apparently by itself and it is very irritating top keep restoring and re-docking it the langauage bar.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, figured it out　(had to bring it up in a conference call, though):

Alt + [カタカナ]  (the key next to the right Alt)

Also, the language/IME toolbar has small toggle buttons (CAPS and KANA), which can be used to toggle Caps-Lock and direct kana input.

Answer (score 3):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

I have to type more to let me post, so I'll wish you a nice day.

Comment: This is the only solution for a non-Japanese keyboard that works on the Lock Screen (a devilish place to accidentally toggle KANA mode in Win 7 as it has no language toolbar). Shame to see it voted down.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, though I acknowledge my keyboard customizations are a bit more extreme than normal.

Comment: This is also the only solution that worked for me, as I was stuck in kana input even when the IME properties screen said I was in romaji!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by clicking Tools on the language bar, then clicking Properties, and finally choose "Romaji Input" under "Input Method".

In Windows 8, Click on the language bar - Language Preferences - For Japanese select Options - Input Method - Microsoft IME Options - Advanced - Input Method - Romaji Input.

[image: Advanced Settings for Microsoft IME]

Comment: see anonymous answer "CTRL+SHIFT+CapsLock" too works!

Answer (score 0):

Under Start > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options

Go to the "Language" tab, click on "Details".

Make sure the settings for Japanese are the same as the settings in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it is set like that. Did not help. I think it was set like that even before it went into the weird "direct-kana-input-mode"..

Comment: try clicking on properties to see what you can find there?

Comment: Sorry, cannot post screen captures right now. There are lots of properties, and they are all in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

It's long time since then but for those who still need a countermeasure: You can press combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> ==> this will switch between Kana input and Romaji input that you may push them accidentally and get angry with the facing situation: Japanese keyboard but no-Japanese typing.