# How can I restore my original IME Romaji input settings?

Tags: windows, keyboard, ime, japanese

the this one, Japanese IME on Windows: switch back to romaji input method (3) did not help.
The problem seems the same.

My Vista home premium version PC, I had been using Microsoft IME to use English and Japanese input using romaji henkan for a long time.
One day, all of a sudden, first when I started up the PC, it has cap lock indicator ON.
So, I press SHIFT key, CAP lock indicator is off!(This I have to do every morning.)

Now when I want to type romaji input to change to Japanese, I switch EN English (United States) to "JP Japanese (Japan) and select input to hiragana input. It worked until that day.

But now when I set to input romaji for hiragana as I used to do and start typing, then it shows Japanese hiragana directly on the display just as keyboard setting as Japanese　日本語109キーボードの配列　as shown in [Wikipedia JIS keyboard](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89).

And I cannot show hiragana as I wanted ( I can convert to Kanji OK) etc. by hitting space key. But its key board arrangement is what I never learned.
Other thing I found is when I hit "`" key, it switches between hiragana and alphabet.
When I see Control panel setting it is the same setting as I have seen.

Please suggest me a solution to get the original setting for IME input mode as I used to do.

John K.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Japanese IME on Windows: switch back to romaji input method](https://superuser.com/questions/37134/japanese-ime-on-windows-switch-back-to-romaji-input-method)

Answer (score 1):

From control panel you go to Region and Language -> text service and input language (tab General)->  click Microsoft Ime -> click properties (tab General) and change  input methode to Romaji Input